# How can I detect unused CSS on my website, across all pages?

Tags: css, css-selectors

In the past I used a Firefox extension called Dust Me Selectors, but it appears to have been abandoned and isn't compatible with Firefox Quantum.

I've been searching for a while and I've failed to come up with a current alternative, other than http://unused-css.com which is a paid-for service.  I'd rather have a tool I could use myself.

This must be something that every developer wonders at some point, so hopefully someone reading this will be able to point me in the right direction!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no css cleanup tools that I'm aware of that can scan an entire site and all of it's css and point out the CSS Rules that are never used.  However, if there was something like this, it could be priceless for many people, including me!

Comment: I guess we have the option of installing an old version of Firefox and then using Dust Me.  Might work.

Comment: That is indeed an option. I just installed Version 51.0.1 from [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox) and the extension from [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/) and it's working fine. It's very unfortunate that Chrome's CSS coverage recording works across AJAX style calls, but not hard page changes, despite giving the impression that it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer, I've found your question when searching for the same thing. Anyway you might be interested by :

https://purifycss.online/.

It removes unused css and you can add multiple urls.

Good luck

PS: I'm editing my answer because I found [another website](https://www.jitbit.com/unusedcss/) doing the unused CSS removal, maybe it will help someone reading this.

Comment: I'm glad someone is working on the problem.  Early days, but if development continues and they implement diffs so you can see what's been removed it could be a pretty useful tool.  Thanks @Chuck

Answer (score -1):

**Honest Answer:** Remove one by one and see if it breaks the style.

**Smart Answer:** Use your browser devtool to disable each css property and watch what will happen.

Comment: Neither of those options come close to the usefulness of the now-defunct Dust Me Selectors browser add-on, sadly.

Comment: Less than useful if you have a site wide CSS file.